# Hibernate OneToMany and ManyToOne error in mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an entity called User with these fields :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "user_id")
private Long id;    

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="userId")   
private List<Survey> survey= new ArrayList<>();
```

And the Survey entity which has :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "SURVEY_ID")
private Long Id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName="user_id")
private User userId;
.....
```

I want one User to be have many Surveys, and each survey is related to one user.
But there is something wrong with the way I've mapped it, cuz as JSON file, when I access allUsers I get this :

```
[{"id":1,"name":"User","lastName":"user","email":"user@user.com","surveyData":[{"userId":{"id":1,"name":"User","lastName":"user","email":"user@user.com","surveyData": ,...... and repeats itself
```

So instead of getting as list the values of the survey data, I get the values of the Users information ?
Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: I think its better to use a Set<Survey> instead of List<Survey>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mapping is correct.

Just use `@JsonManagedReference` in your User class and `@JsonBackReference` in your Survey Class. `@JsonManagedReference` is the forward part of reference – the one that gets serialized normally. `@JsonBackReference` is the back part of reference – it will be omitted from serialization.

In the User Class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="userId")
@JsonManagedReference  
private List<Survey> survey;
```

In the Survey Class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName="user_id")
@JsonBackReference
private User userId;
```

I have 2 remarks:

- If the surveys are not ordered, you can consider to use a Set instead of a List.
- I would also recommend to rename the class variable `userId` in the Survey class to `user`, since it is a User object and no identifier.

Comment: I get an error now :
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.inspire11.etrak.model.User, at table: survey_data, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)]

In the survey class I added a
private User user;
And then the annotation like you, in the getUser function...